# "Operation is not supported on this platform" when registering a function to an event in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, interop

I am trying to add a function to an event handler which will invoke the function on a new data event. The library with the event handler does not officially support .NET core. I am hoping there is way to get it to work despite this, as it would make my life much easier if I could use .NET core for my project.

So far I have tested attaching a function to the event in .NET core 2.2 and it gives me the following error `Operation is not supported on this platform`. If I do something similar using .NET Framework 4.7, it seems to work perfectly fine.

The error essentially boils down to the following line of code

```cs
...
_api.OnNewData += (xml) => Console.WriteLine(xml);
...
```

I have tried different variations of this, but so far I have not found a way to get it to work.

Looking at the stack trace, we can see that this error is raised in the `GetComObjectData` function.

```
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetComObjectData(Object obj, Object key)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComEventsInfo.Find(Object rcw)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComEventsInfo.FromObject(Object rcw)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComEventsHelper.Combine(Object rcw, Guid iid, Int32 dispid, Delegate d)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComAwareEventInfo.AddEventHandler(Object target, Delegate handler)
   at The.Library.I.want.To.Attach.Function.To..ctor() in C:\path\to\code.cs:line 21
```

Is there any way around this, or am I stuck with .NET Framework? Does the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetComObjectData` not support certain functions for .NET core? If so, where can I find more information on this?

Comment: What is `_api` and which platform are you targeting? The error complains about `_api`, not the event handler. Event handlers work in .NET Core. The call stack shows `_api` is a COM object, a technology only available on Windows

Comment: Looks like [this functionality will be released in .NET Core 3.0[(https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31015)

Comment: Amazing, that's it! Upgrading my project to .NET Core 3-preview fixes the problem.